# When can the -ing form of a verb be placed before a noun?

Tags: grammar, word-order, gerunds, participles, ing

My native-speaker's grammatical intuition tells me that:

- There is a **sleeping man** under the tree.

is fine but

- There is a **fishing man** by the river bank.

is wrong.  Why?

Both

- There is a **man sleeping** under the tree.

and

- There is a **man fishing** by the river bank.

are fine.

I've thought about this a little, and I've come up with some grammatical hypotheses, but I'd be very grateful if somebody could point me to a general reference on this matter.

**Addendum:**

Someone asked me what hypotheses I've come up with.

I've identified two cases where an *-ing* modifier can come before a noun:

1. When the *-ing* acts to modify the noun (like an adjective), rather than describe an action being performed at that time, it goes before the verb.  E.g. *flying fish*, *dancing girl*.
2. When the verb suggests a sensory impression.  E.g. *crying baby*, *shining light*.

But there must be at least one more class to account for expressions like *a sleeping man*.

**Second addendum:**

I should clarify precisely what **fishing man** is supposed to mean.  It does not mean *a man who fishes*.  That would be taken care of by case 1 of the hypothesis above.  The intended meaning is *a man who is fishing*.  (Just like *a sleeping man* is supposed to mean *a man who is sleeping* rather than *a man who sleeps*.)

Comment: Wouldn't a 'fishing man' be called a fisherman?

Comment: @RoaringFish Usually, yes.  The plot thickens....

Comment: @Pitarou ~ to be honest, I don't think there is any plot, let alone a thick one, or any sort of mystery. The answer to your question is "we don't say fishing man because we have the word fisherman for those occasions". In other words, we don't fishing man because we don't need to.

Comment: @RoaringFish: You said: **In other words, we don't [{say/use}] _fishing man_ because we don't need to.** William Strunk Jr complained about the word _dependable_ in the 1918 ed. of _The Elements of Style_: "Dependable. A needless substitute for _reliable, trustworthy_."[link](http://www.bartleby.com/141/strunk3.html) Apparently, whether we **need to** or not is an insufficient criterion for using "_needless_" terms and expressions. English speakers have a way of saying whatever they please and whatever pleases them regardless of how it affects the powers that be or not be.

Comment: In real life, [lots of people say *fisherman*, and nobody says *fishing man.](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fisherman%2C+fishing+man&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)

Comment: @tchrist ~ *a man who is fishing* is fishing as we speak, or has started to fish but not finished - he could have gone to buy fish and chips as we speak: "Where is he" ~ " He is fishing." *A man who fishes* has a habit of fishing, and may or may not be fishing as we speak. "What is his hobby?" ~ "He is a man who fishes."

Comment: @RoaringFish: Barrie England found an in-the-wild example of "the fishing man" (see his answer below), so your claim that "nobody says *fishing man" is -- to use contemporary slang -- like totally bogus, dude. It comes out of your head, not from an examination of "real life". This is at best Rationalism, an ancient (17th century) and discredited source of knowledge. While I might agree with "Cogito ergo sum" ("I think; therefore, I am"), I certainly cannot agree with "I think it; therefore, it is". As we **humans** demonstrate every day, anyone can think anything: Fail!

Comment: @BillFranke~ you are using a school- boy argument. One example does not disprove a general truth, it is mere pedantry. My link to Ngram proves my statement true. If you dont like that, just search Google for 'fishing man' and then 'fisherman' and compare the number of hits. This is such an obvious fact that I am surprised I have to explain it.

Comment: @BillFranke This is getting way off-topic.

Comment: @Pitarou: Yes, it's gotten way off topic. But some folks can't stand to admit that they're wrong, so they indulge in food fights. The discussion is now officially over, AFAIC. It's pointless to argue banalities with the North Wind.

Comment: Pointless - the North wind?

Comment: @Edwin: The North Wind & the Sun is an Aesop's Fable. The NW, a blowhard by nature, blustered, & the man pulled his coat tighter around him. The Sun shone brightly & the man took his coat off. **food fight**: 2.2.: "any messy & childish fight" (Urban Dictionary).  Pointless = nothing will change.

Comment: Enough already!

Answer (score 5):

In normal English syntax, single-word modifiers precede the noun they modify, but phrases follow the noun.

So you put the *-ing* word before the noun it modifies when it is acting as an adjective, not as a non-finite verb.  You put the *-ing* word after the noun when it is part of a verbal phrase with other parts in it; you can’t have a long verbal phrase preceding the noun it modifies.

Sometimes the *-ing* word is actually a noun: a *writing desk* is a desk for writing, not a desk that happens to be writing.  But it is still modifying *desk*.  Here are examples of the *-ing* word used as a modifier (either as adjective or a noun) preceding the modified noun:

> answering machine, barking mad, bleeding heart, bowling alley, burning
>   bush, burrowing owl, carrying capacity, changing room, chattering classes,
>   closing credits, coloring book, cooking oil, creeping thyme, dictating
>   machine, drawing board, drilling rig, eating disorder, fighting drunk,
>   firing squad, floating bridge, flying fish, flying buttress, flying fox,
>   flying fuck, growing pains, heating element, holding pen, hopping mad,
>   killing field, landing gear, laughing gas, lending library, lightning bug,
>   magnifying glass, mailing list, missing person, moving walkway, opening
>   night, parking meter, plunging neckline, praying mantis, quaking aspen,
>   revolving door, rising sun, rounding error, scalding hot, shifting use,
>   shouting match, starting line, talking point, thinking cap, trading post,
>   waiting game

On the other hand, here  are pairs of examples where the first one has the *-ing* word first where it acts as a simple adjectival modifer, and where the second one has it acting as an actual verb:

> - the acting director had harsh words for us
> - the director acting in the company’s best interests keeps a tight ship
> - the binding action of this substance
> - the cord binding the two halves together
> - the bouncing ball hit me in the face
> - the ball bouncing down the stairs was lost forever
> - the calling function retains its own private variables
> - the woman calling for a new husband will soon enough find one
> - the carrying case was very heavy
> - the case carrying the lead was heaviest of all
> - the circling vultures drifted ever higher
> - the vultures circling above our heads would wait until we dropped
> - the cooking sausages smelled fabulous
> - the women cooking our breakfast made us wash up first
> - a demanding teacher is hard on the students
> - a teacher demanding full attendance is seldom listened to
> - the facing audience recoiled
> - the man facing the audience cheered

And so on and so forth.  In your case, you could have put *sleeping* afterwards, and had a man sleeping under the tree, but sleeping men like sleeping dogs are not particularly unusual.

However, you would not normally speak of *fishing men*, so you would have a man (who was/is) fishing for something down by the river bank.  If you strained it, you could build up a context in which *fishing men* might contrast with *farming men* or some such, but it would be abnormal.

You might find a man singing in the rain, or you might find a singing man (who is out) in the rain, but you will never find a singing-in-the-rain man. Or to put it more crudely, there is a world of difference between having a fucking idiot in your livingroom and having an idiot fucking in your livingroom.

Comment: -1: I don't think that this answer addresses the OP's question at all. The abundant examples support the claim that adjectives & verbal phrases are different, but we knew that. The question is: **Why is _a sleeping man_ different from _a fishing man_?** Same structure, both men engaged in an activity, both participial adjectives. _A fishing license_ is fine, but why not _a fishing man_? This answer misses the point of the question. The answer is simply that it's not idiomatic usage in this sentence. The grammar exposition is a pyrotechnic show. Fishing men ain't rare neither.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't think you've answered the question.  You've just restated and expanded on it.  **Why** can *sleeping* fulfil the role of adjective when *fishing* can't?

Comment: I've been thinking about the problem. In _a dancing girl_ and _a flying fish_, the ADJs describe a trait associated with the girl and the fish. If _the fishing man_ is a pro, like the _dancing girl_ (_a girl who is dancing_ isn't a pro), then we say _a fisherman_, not _a fishing man_. In _a sleeping man_, the ADJ describes a temporary state of being: everyone sleeps, but not every man fishes, not every girl dances, and not every fish flies. In the movie _The Running Man_, the ADJ described the hero's new occupation: his running wasn't normal everyday running. Does this answer your question?

Comment: @BillFranke You got about as far in your thinking as I'd reached when I wrote my question.  And ... yes ... *The Running Man* popped into my head too!  The power of Hollywood.

Comment: I'm going to point out that a nounal -ing form before another noun doesn't **need** to be modifying it, if only so that I can quote Chomsky: _Flying planes can be dangerous._

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Well, yes; there *flying planes* is a VP in the subject slot, with *planes* the object of the verb *flying*. It's like saying "I enjoy singing songs", as opposed to "I enjoying singing telegrams".  Down this road lie flying fruit and other oddities.

Comment: But it **may** be a modifier.

Comment: @tchrist ('s Answer): I like your list of examples (mainly compound nouns) of -ing forms used as prenominal modifiers. But with barking / hopping (and raving / stark-staring / fighting) mad, fighting drunk (and fit), scalding (and piping / boiling) hot, and freezing cold, dripping wet, lightning-fast, stinking rich, skenning pink and finger-lickin' good, the -ing forms are modifying adjectives and are intensifiers (which I'd class as secondary modifiers, rather than adverbs). Lightning-fast is probably treated as a single lexeme, a compound adjective formed from noun + adjective.

Comment: @tchrist ('s Answer): I've been trying to think of a vaguely acceptable prolix compound-premodifier containing an -ing-form. I think they're becoming more accepted, but not in formal writing. I've come up with a beating-about-the-bush approach, a fighting-in-the-streets situation and a leave-them-laughing-in-the-aisles comedy act.

Comment: Good one. How would you use that attributively - one hyphen or two? I've found an example Trask gives: _the hang-'em-and-flog-'em brigade_.

Comment: Nice explanation, but how does this answer the question? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

Bill is absolutely right in saying that there is nothing grammatically wrong with *fishing man*. It is not likely to be frequently found, but the Corpus of Contemporary American English has this one record from ‘Stern Men’ by Elizabeth Gilbert, published in 2000:

> They were famous lobstermen, superior to every fishing man.

My tentative conclusion is that there is no grammatical rule against placing an adjective ending in *‘-ing’* before a noun. Any counter examples?

Comment: Hmm. Thanks for looking that up for me.  I think I need to clarify my question.  Your example of *a fishing man* means *a man who fishes* and, according to my grammatical intuition, that is perfectly acceptable.  (It falls in the same category as *dancing girl* and *flying fish*.)  The example I had in mind was an example in which *a fishing man* means *a man who is fishing*.

Comment: It's a pertinent distinction, and one I had half in mind when I posted my answer. I suspect this would need some corpus work to get any kind of definitive assessment.

Comment: @Barrie ('s Answer): I can't think of any -ing adjectives that can't be used attributively when they can be used at all with a particular noun.  -ing - form participial adjectives may, of course, be used in constructions using depictive secondary predication: _She found Bill annoying._ This particular example is isoformal with the phase structure _She found Bill sleeping._ - where _sleeping_ is verbal.

Comment: A young (mid-20s) friend from St Vincent (Caribbean English) yesterday immediately responded to this question with _"A fishing man..." isn't idiomatic. It's either "a fisherman" or "a man on the river bank fishing"_.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't say that "There's a fishing man by the river bank" is **wrong**. It's not ungrammatical. It has easily discernible meaning. **It just may not be idiomatic.** That's not a grammar problem. I think most native speakers would probably say *There's a man fishing {by/on/at} the river bank* or *There's a fisherman {by/on/at} the river bank*. Simply a question of style and idiomaticity.

Whether the adjective comes before or after the noun it modifies usually doesn't matter for meaning in English, but *There's a man dying by the river bank* seems to have a different nuance from *There's a dying man by the river bank*. Adjective placement seems to me to affect the focus of the sentences in this case -- maybe in all cases (but I haven't thought enough about it to come to any conclusions). Some adjectives -- well, one for certain -- must come after the noun: this is a usage and not a grammar problem: *There were flowers galore* but **not** *There were galore flowers*. Use a different word or phrase, e.g., *abundant* instead of *galore*, and the usage rules are different: *She had common sense {galore / in abundance}*, *She had abundant common sense*, and *She had an abundance of common sense*.

In French, however, there's a difference in meaning between "un homme pauvre" and "un pauvre homme": the first guy is *penniless* and the second is *pitiful*.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't buy into the whole, "If it's comprehensible, it must be right." school of thought.  There are some things a native speaker just doesn't say under normal circumstances.  Sure, a native speaker may choose to break the rules according to his whim, but there's a difference between choosing to break the rules and there being no rules at all.  In the case of *-ing + verb* there are definitely certain patterns involved, and I would like to know what these patterns are.

Comment: @Pitarou: That there are patterns is indisputable. However, natural language isn't math. The patterns taught in English textbooks published in Japan encourage EFL students to believe that any noun can fit into the noun slot & any adjective can fit into the adjective slot etc. That just isn't true. My answer doesn't say that anything that's comprehensible is right. It says that the reason "There's a fishing man..." isn't normal is that it's not idiomatic. It's comprehensible but not standard. It fits a pattern, but it's an anomaly. It's case-by-case. これは、わかりやすい ですよね？

Comment: I certainly don't subscribe to the Japanese schoolbook model of English! In fact, the reason I'm asking this question is because my own grammatical intuition disagrees with what is in the textbook before me, but I can't articulate **why** the textbook is wrong! In any case, I really don't think this is about case-by-case collocations.  (You say "idiom" but I'm pretty sure you mean "collocation".)  I find the grammar-machine in my head can make judgments about pretty much any pairing of noun & verb, which tells me something more general than collocations is going on.

Comment: Well, no, I didn't say _idiom_ but _idiomatic_, which simply means language that's standard and natural and normally used by native speakers. If it's not _idiomatic_, it's abnormal and unnatural. Richard Nordquist defines a **collocation** as "A familiar grouping of words, especially words that habitually appear together and thereby convey meaning by association." [link](http://grammar.about.com/od/c/g/collocationterm.htm) _A dancing girl_ is an idiom that means "a professional female dancer". It's a collocation, but so is "a girl who is dancing", not an idiom.

Comment: One other point: In spoken English, there would be stress on _dancing_ to indicate the professional dancer, and stress on _girl_ to indicate the nonprofessional who's dancing for the moment. That's not obvious in written English unless **bold** or _italic_ font or a stress mark is used.

Comment: Point taken.  Sorry I misrepresented you.  And good point about word stress too!

Comment: @Bill Franke (c above): If you look for the number of Google hits for "a girl who is dancing" I think you will agree that it does not fulfil the criterion of being composed of words that 'habitually appear together' - it is neither idiom nor collocation, but a 'free association' - merely a permitted string. It is a grouping of familiar words, hardly (in most environments) a familiar grouping of words.

Comment: @Bill Franke (Answer above): I agree that the whole issue of which -ing - form participial adjectives exist seems not to be logically answerable. One can have a _murdering villain_ , a _thieving magpie_ , a _scene-stealing_  villain, but apparently not a _stealing villain_.

Comment: @Pitarou: You say:  **I find the grammar-machine in my head can make judgments about pretty much any pairing of noun & verb. ...** I have a reasonably comprehensive list of about 2500 idiosyncratic verbo-nominal constructions (often non-passivisable; almost always not accepting it-substitution of the direct object), and I still come across exciting surprises that I have to research. A nice one is _weigh anchor_ / _weigh the anchor_ : : _*Have you weighed it yet? / Have you weighed it yet?_

Comment: @Bill Franke (c above): I agree with your differentiation between the senses involved with _idiom_ and _idiomatic_, Bill, and it's the way I use these vital words. However, sadly, the dictionary definitions allow for other senses than the ones we'd prefer.

Comment: @Edwin: I realized that "a girl who is dancing" "does not fulfil the criterion of being composed of words that 'habitually appear together'" and then thought "a/an ___ who/that is PA-ing" is a pattern. Okay. I agree that a pattern doth not a collocation make. But Bertrand Russell said in _Why I Am Not a Christian_ that his life was but the "outcome of accidental collocations of atoms" (M-W3)&[link](http://www.worldmag.com/2009/10/strange_collocation). Why not "accidental collocations of words"? (8-O

Comment: Perhaps for the same reason I am not a non-Christian. No, actually, _collocation_ is used for more habitual assemblages of words (see the good article in Wikipedia). Otherwise the Oxford Collocation Dictionary Online for Advanced English Learners would probably have to be unimaginably large. I don't know when a string qualifies as a collocation, but I _do_ know that _strong tea_ and _powerful computer_ are whilst _strong computer_ and _powerful tea_ aren't.

Comment: @Bill Franke (Ans abv): I've found, at http://www.annies-annex.com/participles_as_adjectives.htm : **Participles as adjectives can be confusing and complicated.  The reasons why one participle can be used in a certain situation, but not in a different context, or why one participle can be used but not another is still being studied by grammarians.  The best way you can learn what is correct and what isn't is to decided each participle individually, and learn by examples of what you study and hear.** It's good to find to find someone who agrees with one's opinion - especially if she has a gun!

Comment: @Edwin: I like what Annie has to say: Case-by-case. Thank you for the link. I've been a Bertrand Russell fan since high school. I accept that he wasn't talking about words.

Comment: @Bill Franke (Ans abv): though there are some adjectives used post-positively either at all times (_manqué, incarnate_) or with different senses (_proper, responsible_), surely _galore_ is a (post-modifying) quantifier (with admittedly a connotation of a happy excess): There were _many_ wonderful sideshows / There were sideshows _galore_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks for the annies-annex link.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, can you flesh that link/quote out to a full answer here? I believe that's really the only right answer to the OP's question, and I would certainly upvote it.

Comment: '[ing-form] placement seems to me to affect the focus of the sentences in this case – maybe in all cases ....' Agreed. 'There's a swimming crocodile over there' and 'There's a crocodile swimming over there' can both sound natural. The second is unmarked (unless 'swimming' or another element is stressed), the whole sentence being the focus. But with the first, the slightly odd word order automatically makes 'swimming' the focus (and this may well be augmented by stress in speech): the implication is that 99% are basking sneakily in the reeds.

Answer (score 3):

In your second addendum you said:

> I should clarify precisely what fishing man is supposed to mean. It
>   does not mean a man who fishes. That would be taken care of by case 1
>   of the hypothesis above. The intended meaning is a man who is fishing.

And that, I think, is the crux of your dilemma.

**"There is a fishing man by the river bank"** Has *two different meanings*

1. There is **a man fishing** by the river bank (verb)
2. There is **a fisherman** by the river bank (noun)

whereas `a sleeping man` only has the one, logical, interpretation.

1. There is **a man sleeping** under the tree.

Hence *fishing man* could either be derived from a verb or a noun.

Both `a fisherman` and `a man fishing` make sense, then I realized that `fisherman` also has two separate meanings!

1. A man catching fish (a profession)
2. A man fishing fish  (a hobbyist)

Now the second sounds decidedly odd, the final words: `fishing fish` is plausible but speakers will naturally avoid saying that.

In order to differentiate the two men; one who catches fish for a living `a fisherman` from one who does it as a pastime, we have the words: `angler` and `angling`.

So perhaps, Pitarou's question:

> My native-speaker's grammatical intuition tells me that:

- There is a fishing man by the river bank.

> is wrong. Why?

has something to do with the word, fish, being used as both a noun and a verb. In addition, `fish` is also a **concrete noun**, not an abstract one. 
Here is a list I composed of verbs that are said to be [**agent verbs**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent_noun). "For example, "driver" is an agent noun formed from the verb "drive". The endings "-er", "-or", and "-ist" are commonly used in English to form agent nouns"

- There is a dancing man at a party = a man dancing or a dancer at a party.
- ... a cooking man in the kitchen (sounds really odd) = a man cooking or a cook in the kitchen.
- ... a cheating man playing in the casino = a man cheating or a cheater in a casino
- ... a cheating man with his girlfriend.
- ... a drinking man by the bar counter.
- ... a gardening man near the tree.
- ... a milking man in the barn.
- ... a painting man outside.
- ... a telephoning man by the kiosk.
- ... a watering man in the garden (very odd!)

All of the above sound "wrong" to me, perhaps it also has something to do with these words being classed as [**deverbal**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deverbal_noun)

> Deverbal nouns are nouns which are derived from verbs or verb
>   phrases, but which behave grammatically purely as nouns, not as verbs.

Answer (score 0):

As I was responding to Barrie English's contribution, an answer to my own question occurred to me.  I hope others will tell me what they think of it.

In a nutshell: the statement *an Xing Y* can be interpreted as meaning either *a Y that Xs* or *a Y that is Xing*. In many contexts only one interpretation makes sense (the other is either absurd, or violates's [Grice's Co-operative Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gricean_maxims)) so we go with that one.  In cases where either interpretation makes sense, we prefer *a Y that Xs* over *a Y that is Xing*.

For instance, in the case of *a sleeping man* we could interpret this as meaning either *a man who sleeps* or *a man who is sleeping*.  But *a man who sleeps* would be an odd thing to say (**all** men sleep!) so we interpret this to mean *a man who is sleeping*.  The same applies to *a crying baby*, *a shining light* and so on.

But in the case of, say, a *dancing girl*, or Barrie English's example of *a fishing man*, here either interpretation would make sense, we favour *a girl who dances* and *a man who fishes*.

Comment: I think your premise is flawed. An *X-ing Y* is a *Y* that is in the act of *X-ing*. That is what -ing means - an activity. A running man is running right now. A *Y* that *Xs* would be an *Xer*. A swimmer is one who swims, a painter is one who paints, a dancer is one who dances, and a man who runs is a runner, not a running man.

Comment: "In cases where either interpretation makes sense, we prefer a Y that Xs over a Y that is Xing." I don't agree with this. _There's a dancing girl in the front room_ is ambiguous without a context. Choosing one or the other indicates a bias unless context supports it. "There's a dancing woman in the front room" is not unambiguous: it means _a woman who is dancing_, not a professional dancer (even though she might be a pro dancer).

Comment: @Bill Franke: Did you not mean to say '. . . is not ambiguous . . .'?

Comment: @BarrieEngland: Yes, I did. Thank you for pointing that out. :-)

Comment: I take your point, Bill.  So how does this sound: in *determiner + verbing + noun* the verb must be considered, first and foremost, as a **modifier** of the noun.  Depending on the context, it can be interpreted as *a noun which verbs*, *a noun which is verbing*, or sometimes it can be left unspecified.  (E.g. if I see a winged monkey in the sky, I might say, "Oh! A flying monkey." and it can be taken either way.) Sometimes the verb can mean something else entirely (consider "fucking").

Comment: This sounds better to me. Maybe, though, it would be good to say _First and foremost, it's necessary to determine whether the expression is a standard idiom_. It's not easy to answer questions like this without more research and thought because someone will likely find an exception that squelches the explanation. I was thinking of _a dancing bear_ earlier. They don't dance unless trained to. Monkeys don't fly except in _The Wizard of Oz_. If someone said _a flying monkey_, I'd think it had been thrown; if _a dancing bear_, I'd think _a trained circus bear_. Case by case for me.

Comment: Also, it's a present participial adjective rather than a verb. Regardless of what part of speech it is, it has a specific function. We can call it an adjective or the "-ing" word. The terminology isn't important; the function is. What does it modify: (1) a consistent trait or (2) a temporary state or action?

Comment: A 'sleeping policeman' is nicely ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Is it because 'sleeping man' may be regarded as state of being for the man, but not 'fishing man'?

Comment: Sleeping's a temporary state of being; everybody sleeps. If someone's called "The Sleeping Man", then he (almost) never wakes up. He's either comatose or extremely narcoleptic. Fishing's either a hobby or a profession. Not everyone {fishes/goes fishing}. A fisherman's either an ordinary man who's fishing because it's his hobby or a professional catcher of fish who sells his catch to make his living. The term's ambiguous. It's not normal English to say "There's a fishing man over there": we have the word "fisherman", an idiom, as well as the sentence "There's a man who is fishing over there".

Comment: We'd usually ellipt: There's a man fishing over there. We could re-arrange: There's a man over there, fishing. Again, these are verbal rather than adjectival uses of the -ing-form.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Even the other sentence sounds more natural when rearranged thus: "There is a man sleeping under the tree." That should be the correct verbal usage.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and came across this thread.
This is my guess.
We can use the -ing form in front of a noun when the action is something that doesn't involve another object.
Sleeping is just lying a body on a surface. The same goes with a dancing girl, a crawling baby, a walking man. We don't require anything else other than our body.
If the action involves another object, it sounds strange to use the -ing form.
A fishing man - fishing will require a fishing pole. 
A punching man - the man will need to punch something.

Comment: I think this comes very close. 'We don't drive if there's a risk of a blizzard occurring' is a counter-example. And of course 'There are revolting peasants in the south of the country' and  'There are peasants revolting in the south of the country' have very different default meanings. The postnominal positioning is more verby, the prenominal more adjectival.