# Scan Method vs Scanning Method

Tags: ambiguity

The question here is what is the meaning of the two:

1. Scan Method
2. Scanning Method

My assumption is that the interpretations are, respectively:

1. A method which describes how the scanning procedure is performed.
2. A method which has the inherent ability to scan.

While this sounds logical to me, it was pointed out by a colleague that counter-examples exist. For example:

1. Swimming Pool
2. Parking Place

What, then, is the correct usage pattern in all of these cases?

Comment: Both forms of *scan/scanning* could have either interpretation. Just be consistent in what you use.

Comment: [When can the -ing form of a verb be placed before a noun?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/83675/when-can-the-ing-form-of-a-verb-be-placed-before-a-noun)

Comment: Another usage (for either phrase) could be as a qualifier, to distinguish from another method that does not involve scanning.

Answer (score 2):

The example is similar to the use of *sort/sorting algorithm*. The OED defines a *sort program* as *a program written to perform a sort*. Similarly a *scan method* may be defined as *a method for performing a scan*. *Scanning* is defined as *the action of performing a scan*. Therefore,  there is no difference between *scan method* and *scanning method*.

Maybe there are some differences in meaning depending on the field of application, but this is not a general view.