# eligibility criterion for an -ing form to serve as a deverbal adjective

Tags: word-usage, phrases, expressions, verbs, adjectives

*a dog which is barking* can be rephrased as **a barking dog**; I am wondering whether  *a patient who is coughing* can be rephrased as **a coughing patient**?

similarly, can we rephrase *something (such as a dog, a train, etc.) which is running* as **a running dog/ train, etc.**?

the -ing form of some verbs can serve as a deverbal adjective, while that of others cannot. I am wondering what the eligibility criterion should be for an -ing form to function as a deverbal adjective so as to serve as a premodifier for a noun?

Comment: The availability of the participle depends on whether the noun could have multiple relationships to the verb.  Book, etc., titles routinely pun on this possibility, e.g., "Judging Amy."  Is a "coughing patient" a patient who is coughing or a patient who is being *treated* for coughing? When the mind won't have to sort out these possibilities, as in the case of a barking dog, the participle works. Otherwise, it doesn't.

Comment: "Barking" and "coughing" are not adjectives, but verb phrases. They have none of the properties of indisputable adjectives, and hence cannot belong in that class. Others do, e.g. "entertaining", as in "an entertaining film".

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Running_dog
We don't normally speak of a train running (except possibly to mean that the service hasn't been cancelled), but we can certainly refer to a moving train, passing train, and so on.

Comment: Relevant (not the same, though, since as BillJ said, word order isn't necessarily based on part of speech): [When can the -ing form of a verb be placed before a noun?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/83675)

Answer (score 1):

> *a barking dog  /  a coughing patient  / a sleeping child*

I've added the last example as it belongs in the same category as the other two.

I would say that the *ing* forms here are verb phrases, not adjectives.  Even if they were adjectives, they would not be deverbal ones, but adjectives formed by conversion from verbs.

These attributive modifiers are best analysed as verb phrases, not adjectives, for a number of reasons:

They can't be modified by "very".

They can't occur as complement to complex-intransitive verbs like "become" or "seem" (we can't say *"It seemed/became quite barking" or *"He seemed/became quite coughing/ sleeping").

They can't occur as complement to complex-transitive verbs like "find" (we can't say *"I found it quite barking" or *"I found him quite coughing/sleeping").

The range of expressions that can occur as pre-head modifier to a noun is very large and varied: we don't want to call them all adjectives. "Barking", "coughing" and "sleeping" don't have the properties of indisputable adjectives and hence can't belong in that class.

Comment: Good analysis. Would you class say 'striking' (very striking; the similarity appeared quite striking; he found her quite striking) as having achieved 'true adjective' status?